# How to get list of all public videos from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get video ids of all public facebook videos, Is there any way to do this may be from graph api?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

You can only search for Users, Pages, Events, .... but the Public Post Search is deprecated so you can´t get public videos.